# Speeding up resampling end- and startdate for each group, but keep the gaps in between the dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'startdate': ['2013-03-04', '2012-01-02', '2012-08-06', '2013-02-04', '2013-05-07'],
                   'enddate': ['2013-03-07', '2012-01-06', '2012-08-10', '2013-02-11', '2013-05-09'],
                   'regnr': [111, 111, 111, 222, 222],
                   'contracttype': ['ABU', 'ABU', 'ULDB', 'ULDB', 'ABU']})

df['startdate'], df['enddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate']), pd.to_datetime(df['enddate'])

print(df)

   startdate    enddate  regnr contracttype
0 2013-03-04 2013-03-07    111          ABU
1 2012-01-02 2012-01-06    111          ABU
2 2012-08-06 2012-08-10    111         ULDB
3 2013-02-04 2013-02-11    222         ULDB
4 2013-05-07 2013-05-09    222          ABU
```

What I want is to expand (resample) the startdate and enddate to daily time series. But what is important, is that we keep the gaps in between the dates. So if you look at `regnr = 111`, we see in index 2 `enddate = 2012-11-04`, while the next `startdate = 2013-03-04` on index 0. So there's a gap between these dates.

---

So **expected output** is:

```
         date  regnr contracttype
0  2013-03-04    111          ABU
1  2013-03-05    111          ABU
2  2013-03-06    111          ABU
3  2013-03-07    111          ABU
4  2012-01-02    111          ABU
5  2012-01-03    111          ABU
6  2012-01-04    111          ABU
7  2012-01-05    111          ABU
8  2012-01-06    111          ABU
9  2012-08-06    111         ULDB
10 2012-08-07    111         ULDB
11 2012-08-08    111         ULDB
12 2012-08-09    111         ULDB
13 2012-08-10    111         ULDB
14 2013-02-04    222         ULDB
15 2013-02-05    222         ULDB
16 2013-02-06    222         ULDB
17 2013-02-07    222         ULDB
18 2013-02-08    222         ULDB
19 2013-02-09    222         ULDB
20 2013-02-10    222         ULDB
21 2013-02-11    222         ULDB
22 2013-05-07    222          ABU
23 2013-05-08    222          ABU
24 2013-05-09    222          ABU
```

---

**So what is the problem?**

I have a working solution, but it's kind of slow. I takes ~90 - 110 seconds for a dataframe of 66k rows which will eventually be resampled to 10.5 million rows.

Here's the working solution:

```
def resample_data(df):
    """
    :param df: dataframe where datetime has to be resampled to daily
    :return: resampled dataframe
    """
    tables = []

    for _, d in df.groupby('regnr'):
        for __, data in d.iterrows():
            dates = pd.date_range(data['startdate'], data['enddate'])
            dfn = pd.DataFrame({'regnr': data['regnr'],
                                'contracttype': data['contracttype']}, index=dates)
            tables.append(dfn)

    df = pd.concat(tables).rename_axis('date').reset_index()

    return df
```

---

**Vectorized solution, but does not work**

So I tried a vectorized method (expect for the apply in groupby), but this does not work, since it will fill the gaps in between the dates.

```
dfn = df.melt(id_vars=['regnr', 'contracttype'], 
              value_name='date', 
              var_name='start_end').drop('start_end', axis=1)

dfn = (
    dfn.groupby('regnr').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').first().ffill())
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    .reset_index()
)

print(dfn)

          date  regnr contracttype
0   2012-01-02  111.0          ABU
1   2012-01-03  111.0          ABU
2   2012-01-04  111.0          ABU
3   2012-01-05  111.0          ABU
4   2012-01-06  111.0          ABU
..         ...    ...          ...
521 2013-05-05  222.0         ULDB
522 2013-05-06  222.0         ULDB
523 2013-05-07  222.0          ABU
524 2013-05-08  222.0          ABU
525 2013-05-09  222.0          ABU

[526 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: ```df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(row.startdate, row.enddate, freq='D'),
               'regnr': row.regnr,
               'contracttype': row.contracttype}, columns=['date', 'regnr', 'contracttype']) 
           for row in df.itertuples()], ignore_index=True) ``` One bit of optimization here from what you did is, I used `itertuples()` that is quicker than `iterrows()` since it doesn't do any of the type checking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it meets the requirements, but I think the following code can handle it. However, I haven't checked the execution speed.

```
tables = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=['Date','regnr','contracttype'])
for i in range(len(df)):
    days = pd.DataFrame({'Date':list(pd.date_range(df.startdate[i], df.enddate[i])),
            'regnr':[df.regnr[i]]*len(pd.date_range(df.startdate[i],df.enddate[i])),
            'contracttype':[df.contracttype[i]]*len(pd.date_range(df.startdate[i], df.enddate[i]))})
tables = pd.concat([tables, days], ignore_index=True)

    Date    regnr   contracttype
0   2013-03-04  111 ABU
1   2013-03-05  111 ABU
2   2013-03-06  111 ABU
3   2013-03-07  111 ABU
4   2012-01-02  111 ABU
5   2012-01-03  111 ABU
6   2012-01-04  111 ABU
7   2012-01-05  111 ABU
8   2012-01-06  111 ABU
9   2012-08-06  111 ULDB
10  2012-08-07  111 ULDB
11  2012-08-08  111 ULDB
12  2012-08-09  111 ULDB
13  2012-08-10  111 ULDB
14  2013-02-04  222 ULDB
15  2013-02-05  222 ULDB
16  2013-02-06  222 ULDB
17  2013-02-07  222 ULDB
18  2013-02-08  222 ULDB
19  2013-02-09  222 ULDB
20  2013-02-10  222 ULDB
21  2013-02-11  222 ULDB
22  2013-05-07  222 ABU
23  2013-05-08  222 ABU
24  2013-05-09  222 A
```

Comment: I pasted the results. I would appreciate it if you could point out where I am wrong.